# How to implement a 2-layer PCB antenna on a 4 or 6 layer stack-up?

Tags: pcb-antenna

I am new to antenna designs. Lots of design guides mentions that no ground is required on the second layer (antenna on the TOP layer, IFA or MIFA for example.)

I'm wondering to how to implement a 2-layer PCB antenna (MIFA) design for example on a 4 or 6 layer stack-up (prepreg + core) PCB.

Should I simply not do ground pouring from 2nd layer of the stack-up and then tuning since the dielectric material (prepreg and core) are slightly different?

Comment: What type of antenna are you designing?

Comment: @Andyaka I try to implement this IF antenna (TI design notes DN023) on an existing 4-Layer stack-up PCB. The app notes talks only the 2 layer PCB.

Comment: From my observation, commonly all other signals then the antenna are removed from all other layers then top around the area of the antenna with approx. 5mm cleareance. I would do this, get a cheap demo-board and test it. Should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know, no ground plane needed underneath the antenna.

All you need to do is,

- Copy the existing antenna design (with exact dimensions) to the top layer,
- Remove all the copper that drops under the antenna on the remaining layers.

Good thing is that the PCB thickness is unimportant here. So it doesn't matter if the PCB is 1.0 mm or 1.6 mm, or if it has 2 or 16 layers. As long as you leave the area without any copper you're fine.